# On Search route, when user tries to search data, css breaks

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, remix.run

I am working on Remix 2.8.1.
In routes folder, I have a index.tsx route and search route on which i am fetching data through APIs. When i fetches data of search route, it breaks my one css file, tries to upload it from a different path instead of the actual path.

By default, it should fetch the existing css file as working on other routes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.